# DXR Installation - Python error

Tags: python

I am currently trying to install the Mozzila code indexer called DXR

http://dxr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started.html

I used Ubuntu14.04 installed on VirtualBox to make things work.

Here is the steps that I did:

1. Download dxr at /home/alex/dxr using git.
2. Install all necessary dependencies.
3. cd /home/alex/dxr; make

Then dxr can make successfully. Now indexing the code and serving a host

4. make test

Here is the error I got:

```
Starting tree 'code'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alex/dxr/venv/bin/dxr", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('dxr', 'console_scripts', 'dxr')()
  File "/home/alex/dxr/dxr/cli/__init__.py", line 29, in main
    return dxr.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/alex/dxr/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 991, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/alex/dxr/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 837, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/alex/dxr/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 464, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/alex/dxr/dxr/cli/index.py", line 26, in index
    index_and_deploy_tree(tree, verbose=verbose)
  File "/home/alex/dxr/dxr/build.py", line 61, in index_and_deploy_tree
    index_name = index_tree(tree, es, verbose=verbose)
  File "/home/alex/dxr/dxr/build.py", line 244, in index_tree
    {})
  File "/home/alex/dxr/dxr/es.py", line 110, in create_index_and_wait
    es.create_index(index, settings=settings)
  File "/home/alex/dxr/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyelasticsearch/client.py", line 93, in decorate
    return func(*args, query_params=query_params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/alex/dxr/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyelasticsearch/client.py", line 1033, in create_index
    query_params=query_params)
  File "/home/alex/dxr/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyelasticsearch/client.py", line 281, in send_request
    raise exc.info
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', error(111, 'Connection refused'))
```

Does anyone have experience of installing DXR, please share your knowledge.

Thank you so much.

Alex

Comment: Try after disabling the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

DXR by default expects ElasticSearch to be open on 127.0.0.1 port 5000.

That will be enough to get started but you can see full deployments docs at https://dxr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment.html.